# Job class not found for Quartz 2.1 in Play 2.0

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, quartz-scheduler

Quartz 2.1.7
Play 2.1

I've set up quartz to use JDBC job store to store all job details and triggers. Here's my config

```
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 3
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = Sched1
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = 1
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.export = false
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.proxy = false

org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass =          
org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate

org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = TaskScheduler
org.quartz.dataSource.TaskScheduler.driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
org.quartz.dataSource.TaskScheduler.URL = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/quartz    
org.quartz.dataSource.TaskScheduler.user = quartz
org.quartz.dataSource.TaskScheduler.password = quartz
org.quartz.dataSource.TaskScheduler.maxConnections = 1
```

After schedule a new job, I got these exception

```
org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't retrieve job because a required class was not found: jobs.Counter [See nested exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jobs.Counter]
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.retrieveJob(JobStoreSupport.java:1378)
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$9.execute(JobStoreSupport.java:1366)
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3798)
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX.executeInLock(JobStoreTX.java:93)
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeWithoutLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3703)
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.retrieveJob(JobStoreSupport.java:1363)
at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.getJobDetail(QuartzScheduler.java:1465)
at org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler.getJobDetail(StdScheduler.java:489)
at utils.SchedulerUtils.getAlljob(SchedulerUtils.java:44)
at controllers.Task.index(Task.java:23)
at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(routes_routing.scala:65)
at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(routes_routing.scala:65)
at play.core.Router$HandlerInvoker$$anon$6$$anon$2.invocation(Router.scala:141)
at play.core.Router$Routes$$anon$1.invocation(Router.scala:322)
at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$1.call(JavaAction.scala:31)
at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$2.apply(JavaAction.scala:74)
at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$2.apply(JavaAction.scala:73)
at play.libs.F$Promise$PromiseActor.onReceive(F.java:420)
at akka.actor.UntypedActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(UntypedActor.scala:159)
at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:425)
at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:386)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:230)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:212)
at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$MailboxExecutionTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:502)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:262)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:975)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1478)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jobs.Counter
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at sbt.PlayCommands$$anonfun$53$$anonfun$55$$anon$2.loadClass(PlayCommands.scala:535)
at org.quartz.simpl.InitThreadContextClassLoadHelper.loadClass(InitThreadContextClassLoadHelper.java:72)
at org.quartz.simpl.CascadingClassLoadHelper.loadClass(CascadingClassLoadHelper.java:114)
at org.quartz.simpl.CascadingClassLoadHelper.loadClass(CascadingClassLoadHelper.java:138)
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate.selectJobDetail(StdJDBCDelegate.java:873)
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.retrieveJob(JobStoreSupport.java:1373)
... 27 more
```

After browsing around, Some people suggesting adding these 2 properties, but that doesn't seem to help at all

```
org.quartz.threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread = true
org.quartz.scheduler.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializer = true
```

Does anyone ran into the same issue and found a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a package lib in your app folder and add Quartz' libraries there.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do add the lib package to class path. I've been letting play handle all the dependency in Build.scala since play 2.0 deprecate the lib folder ... Here's what I tried: dded a lib package in app folder then add the jar file to it, removed the quartz dependency in Build.scala, but now the code doesn't compile because it couldn't find the jar ... I

Comment: I ended up package a jar for the Counter class file and add it to the lib folder .... and it works. This tells me the class files defined in app folder are somehow not in the classpath ... Did I totally miss something ?